# What exactly does JSF h:form tag

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

Could someone explain in own words how exactly h:form works and what is it good for ?
I am completely new to JSF and I noticed strange behaviour.
Let's say I have a button which redirect me to home page like this:

**h:commandButton value="back" action="home?faces-redirect=true"**

When I don't wrap this button into h:form tag button simply doesn't work...
What exactly do h:form behind the scene ? I have read official documentation but I don't feel that I know how it works...

Thanks

Comment: I suggest to take a step back and learn some basic HTML first. E.g. http://www.htmldog.com/guides/html/beginner/forms JSF is in the context of this question just a HTML code generator. Rightclick, view source, etc in browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It places `<form />` HTML tag into rendered result (pure HTML sent to client). The benefit of this is that all elements inside `<h:form />` can use POST (or GET eventually) request to send informations to the server.

The `<h:commandButton />` uses this kind of request so it works only in `<h:form />`. So do other form elements like `<h:inputText />` etc. These elements need to be contained in `<h:form />` so information entered by user can be sent to the server and processed.

Also, some other components that don't seem to be form elements also need to use `<h:form />` because they send information to the server. An example of such component may be PrimeFaces (extension library of JSF) data table (`<p:dataTable />`).